# Application is not deploying on Glassfish 3.1.2

Tags: glassfish-3

I made a web service. I have made 2 or 3 services and have deployed these on the glass fish. On each service i used package name like pk.mazars.basitMahmood.calculate, pk.mazars.basitMahmood.weather and so on. Means pk.mazars.basitMahmood is common in all packages name. Now i developed a web service on eclipse and now when i try to deploy it, i am getting the following error

```
cannot Deploy ResourceAEAR
org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Deployment Error for module: ResourceAEAR:  
Error occurred during deployment: Exception while loading the app : 
java.lang.Exception: WEB0113: Virtual server [server] already has a web module 
[AndroidBackendAuthentication.war] loaded at [/AndroidBackendAuthentication]; 
therefore web module [ResourceAEAR#AndroidBackendAuthentication.war] cannot be 
loaded at this context path on this virtual server. . Please see server.log for
 more details.
at com.sun.enterprise.jst.server.sunappsrv.SunAppServerBehaviour.
publishDeployedDirectory(SunAppServerBehaviour.java:859)
...
```

What is that error mean. How can i resolve it?  I also did some google on this error but unable to find exactly where is the problem. So please help :(

Thanks